# Fetch data from database with same column entries?

Tags: php, mysql

Have got a database with column as

```
Username      Password     Chain Name
12345         12345        ASDFG
12345         12345        QWERT
12345         12345        ZXCVB
```

I am taking `Username` and `Password` as input from the user and want to display all the `Chain Name` associated with this username and password.

Uploading the PHP for same.

```
<?php  
  include('includes/config.php');

  if(isset($_POST['userid'],$_POST['pid'])){    
    $userid = trim($_POST["userid"]);
    $pid = trim($_POST["pid"]);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_store WHERE username = '$userid' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo "$rowcount";

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    echo "Store code".'<br/>';
    echo $row['Chain_Name'].'<br/>'.'<br/>';
  }
?>
```

Kindly suggest what needs to be done to get all the `Chain Name`.

Comment: Where’s the `}` in this PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_store WHERE username = '$userid' AND password='$pid'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo "$rowcount";
    $chainName = array();
    //if($rowcount>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

           echo "Store code".'<br/>';
         echo $row['Chain_Name'].'<br/>'.'<br/>'; 
         $chainName[] = $row['Chain_Name'];
      }
      print_r($chainName); this will have all chain names
```

ALternate solution

```
 $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT("Chain_Name") as allChainName FROM tbl_store WHERE username = '$userid' AND password='$pid'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo "$rowcount";
        $chainName = array();
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$chainName = explode(",",$row['allChainName']);
 print_r($chainName); // this will have all chain names
```